# Connect Colabatory to Local runtime with token

Tags: google-colaboratory

When one creates a runtime using a conda installed Jupyter server (don't know if it's true with other meta packages) the server starts and provides a connection port and a token. e.g.

```
 $ jupyter notebook 
[I 16:09:59.582 NotebookApp] [nb_conda_kernels] enabled, 11 kernels found
[I 16:09:59.831 NotebookApp] [nb_anacondacloud] enabled
[I 16:09:59.834 NotebookApp] [nb_conda] enabled
[I 16:09:59.863 NotebookApp] ✓ nbpresent HTML export ENABLED
[W 16:09:59.863 NotebookApp] ✗ nbpresent PDF export DISABLED: No module named 'nbbrowserpdf'
[I 16:09:59.865 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/peter/Desktop
[I 16:09:59.865 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 16:09:59.865 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 16:09:59.865 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=f2e38594d77977a7e8d0d53d31699037e8c184ee108191ea
[I 16:09:59.865 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

Is there  way to give the colabatory local connection settings the token (won't connect without it)

I'm following the instructions here https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html

Update: While it is possible to connect if the token is set to blank e.g. with

```
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com' --port=8888 --NotebookApp.token=''
```

This is slightly sub optimal, as the token gives a little more security. Important I guess if the juptyer server is exposed.

Answer (score 0):

Colab doesn't connect without a token, so I put in a previous token and it works!